# Why does a print statement not execute when method called from "empty" main

Tags: java

(I really don't know how to phrase the question any better. I'm sure there is a concept involved here that I'm unaware of, so please suggest a better phrasing if you can--or direct me to an answered question if this turns out to be a duplicate)

I've been playing around in Java and found some behavior I can't explain. In the following code, I'd expect a `0` to be printed. However, nothing is printed. The only possible explanation I can come up with is that the main method ends before the printstream is flushed, but it doesn't make sense to me why that might be. In short, **whats up with this code printing nothing instead of `0`?**

```
class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {

        if(false && method()){

        }
    }
    public static boolean method(){
        System.out.println(0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the method is not called. The `false` causes the and to [short-ciruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

```
if(false & method()){ // <-- body will not execute, but the evaluation
                      //     does not short circuit.
```

**or**

```
if(false || method()){ // <-- body will execute, method() is true
```

**or**

```
if(method() && false){ // <-- body will not execute, because of false.
```

will work as you expected.

Comment: Ah it really is that simple... Why would the first example `false & method` be any different? Because it's bitwise? It'll still always lead the argument to be false

Comment: Because it is [eager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation), the second short-circuits. They are different operators.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the explanation